# how to order by column of related table in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two table and their models named Attendance and Line,
I am trying to get all from 'attendances' which is group by line_id and order by line names

here is a portion of what I have tried

```
public function lineWiseReport(Attendance $attendance){
        $repository = $this->repository;


        if(Input::has('date')){
            $date = Input::get('date');
            $attn->where('date','like','%'.$date.'%');
            $attendances = $attn
                ->where('employee_type_id',2)
                ->orderBy('lines.name', 'ASC') //how to do this?
                ->get()->groupBy('line_id');
        }else{
            $date = '';
            $attendances = [];
        }
    }


class Attendance extends Model
{
public function line()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Line::class);
    }
}
```

Now I get only group by line_id but I want it to be sorted like Line A, Line B, Line C in a ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to join with the `lines` table before you can use values from that table.

```
$attendances = $attn
    ->join('lines', 'lines.id', '=', 'line_id')
    ->where('employee_type_id', 2)
    ->orderBy('lines.name', 'ASC') //how to do this?
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('line_id');
```

This might however return more records if a model contains more lines.

Comment: ok its working, but I have two types of lines one is text like A, B, C and another is numeric like 1,2,3, I want all texts first in asc then numbers, can you help me on this?